# Size distribution of nanoparticles from a transmission electron microscopic image

Tags: image-processing

I have found a [research article](http://www.lpi.usra.edu/meetings/lpsc2013/pdf/2906.pdf) about Martian sand grain size determination from the image using Mathematica (Figure 2 in the linked article). They have not provided any detail of the methodology. It could have many applications in biology specially in the microscopy.

May be it is simple, but I have no idea how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated. I have enclosed an image of gold nanoparticles here. There's a reference size bar at the bottom right of the image.

[image: Gold nanoparticles]

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15921. Also see [this blogpost](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/) on wolfram.com

Comment: Related questions: [25137](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25137/finding-areas-of-beings-in-microscopic-image), [27075](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27075/image-processing-concrete-test-blocks)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

We can try the following script to specify that each particle strictly contained in the field-of-view should be treated as a morphological component (the scale bar an text is removed with `DeleteSmallComponents`, which can be manually adjusted):

```
particleImage = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/udW8X.jpg"]
m = DeleteSmallComponents[DeleteBorderComponents[MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate[Binarize[particleImage]]]]];
m // Colorize
```

[image]

Notice here that I had to apply `ColorNegate` since *Mathematica* v9 apparently considers bright pixels to define regions of interest.

We can then use [`ComponentMeasurements`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ComponentMeasurements.html) to calculate something like an equivalent disk radius for each particle (there are a lot of other size measurement options):

```
equivDiskRadii = ComponentMeasurements[m, "EquivalentDiskRadius"][[All,2]]
(* {15.6759, 13.923, 14.5819, 13.4698, 14.9909, 12.5904, 13.8772, 15.5229, 14.8308, 
    15.8174, 13.5875, 14.6906, 14.6906, 14.7986, 14.2507, 12.8902, 14.1498, 13.8772,
    14.8629, 14.7014, 14.161, 15.2122, 15.5332, 14.4393, 13.4106, 16.4875, 14.0822, 
    14.8629, 14.3619, 14.9909, 14.56, 13.159, 16.6794, 15.3372, 15.757, 14.6472, 15.0439, 
    14.4062, 14.1047, 14.2395, 13.1953, 14.3619, 16.0472} *)
```

which is measured in pixels.  We can manually check that the $20$ nm scale bar is about $\approx 60$ pixels in length, and as such convert the equivalent disc radii to nanometers:

```
equivDiskRadiiNanometers = equivDiskRadii * 20/60
(* {5.2253, 4.641, 4.86063, 4.48993, 4.99697, 4.1968, 4.62573, 5.1743, 4.9436, 5.27247, 
    4.52917, 4.89687, 4.89687, 4.93287, 4.75023, 4.29673, 4.7166, 4.62573, 4.9543, 4.90047, 
    4.72033, 5.07073, 5.17773, 4.8131, 4.4702, 5.49583, 4.69407, 4.9543, 4.7873, 4.99697, 
    4.85333, 4.38633, 5.5598, 5.1124, 5.25233, 4.8824, 5.01463, 4.80207, 4.70157, 4.7465, 
    4.39843, 4.7873, 5.34907} *)
```

Is this sort of what you're looking for?

---

The command:

```
ComponentMeasurements[m, "Properties"]
```

yields all of the possible built-in measurements that can be made on the components:

```
{"AdjacentBorderCount", "AdjacentBorders", "Area", "AreaRadiusCoverage", "AuthalicRadius", "BoundingBox", "BoundingBoxArea", "BoundingDiskCenter", "BoundingDiskCoverage", "BoundingDiskRadius", "CaliperElongation", "CaliperLength", "CaliperWidth", "Centroid", "Circularity", "Complexity", "ConvexArea", "ConvexCount", "ConvexCoverage", "ConvexPerimeterLength", "ConvexVertices", "Count", "Dimensions", "Eccentricity", "Elongation", "EmbeddedComponentCount", "EmbeddedComponents", "EnclosingComponentCount", "EnclosingComponents", "EquivalentDiskRadius", "EulerNumber", "ExteriorNeighborCount", "ExteriorNeighbors", "FilledCircularity", "FilledCount", "Fragmentation", "Holes", "InteriorNeighborCount", "InteriorNeighbors", "Label", "LabelCount", "Length", "Mask", "MaxCentroidDistance", "MaxPerimeterDistance", "MeanCaliperDiameter", "MeanCentroidDistance", "Medoid", "MinCentroidDistance", "MinimalBoundingBox", "NeighborCount", "Neighbors", "Orientation", "OuterPerimeterCount", "PerimeterCount", "PerimeterLength", "PolygonalLength", "Rectangularity", "SemiAxes", "Width"}
```