# How can I properly Partition "IntensityData" output from "ComponentMeasurements"? (Recovering the (x, y) dimensions of a rect. morph. component?)

Tags: image-processing

When I ask `ComponentMeasurements` to return "IntensityData" for some set of rectangular morphological components:

```
m = MorphologicalComponents[image, Method -> "BoundingBox"];
intensityDataArray = ComponentMeasurements[{m, image}, "IntensityData"][[All, 2]];
```

The pixel value data is returned as an unpartitioned one-dimensional array.  This makes it difficult for me to understand where a particular pixel is in the image.  Now, if I know the exact dimensions of each morphological component, I suppose I could fix the problem using `Partition`.  I could also fix the problem with `Partition` if I could ask for something like a bounding square instead of a bounding rectangular box, though I don't think this is possible (is it?).

Besides manually measuring the dimensions of each rectangular morphological component, is there a workaround to fix this problem?

Letting `m` consist of strictly rectangular morphological components, it would, for example, be very nice to be able to write something like:

```
ComponentMeasurements[m, "Dimensions"][[All, 2]]
```

And have this return something like:

```
{{5,8}, {87, 40}, {7, 7}, ...}
```

Meaning that we have morphological components of dimensions $(x, y) = (5 \times 8)$, $(87 \times 40)$, $(7 \times 7)$, and so forth.  Here, we're provided ordered values for the extent of the component along the $x$- and $y$-axes, respectively, allowing us to trivially use `Partition` to restore the cropped section of an image underlying a morphological component (i.e. the image one would have if a morphological component is used as a "cropping mask").

---

Clarification: Masking approaches are really neat, but not quite what I'm looking for here unless they're part of a larger approach.  I need a method of grabbing the pixel data strictly underlying a morphological component (for a set of morphological components) and retaining $(x, y)$ data for each pixel.  My downstream procedure then does further image processesing on this rectangular matrix.  If I do a matrix multiplication masking procedure, I still need to trim away the dark space to get down to a bounding box (the size of the morphological component mask).

Also, it seems a little wasteful to have to perform multiplication operation on all pixels in the image to accomplish my goal?

Comment: I think `"IntensityData"` is meant to be used for histogram processing, where the position of the intensities doesn't matter. Couldn't you just measure the `"BoundingBox"` instead and pass the result to `ImageTrim` to cut out the right area of the image? You can measure `"Mask"` to get a sparse array where the pixels of the component are set to 1. (I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, I that's what I use when I need both the intensity and the location of the pixels in a component.)

Comment: @nikie How do I ask for the dimensions of a rectangular morphological component?  If I can do this, I can just use Partition, right?  I mean, I can figure this out up to rotation and reflection symmetries using metrics like Elongation, but how do I nail down the orientation as well?

Comment: @nikie I'll also note that I have maybe a few thousand of these morphological components, so I'm kind of hoping for some automated solution.

Comment: Use Partition on the returned IntensityData? I don't think so, because some lines might be longer than others. At least unless the components are all perfectly rectangular.

Comment: @nikie I'm specifying that the morphological components are bounding boxes, and must be rectangular.  I'll try to clarify this better in the question.

Comment: A related question might be this link http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27075/image-processing-concrete-test-blocks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm answering the question you posted in a comment:

> but how do I then crop to a bounding box around that component

List I said, the easiest way is probably to measure the `"BoundingBox"`es and pass them to `ImageTrim`:

```
image=ExampleData[{"TestImage","APC"}]
```

[image]

```
m=MorphologicalComponents[Binarize@ColorNegate[ColorConvert[image,"Grayscale"]]];
Colorize[m]
```

[image]

```
components=ComponentMeasurements[{m,image},{"Area","BoundingBox"},#1>100&];
ImageTrim[image,#]&/@components[[All,2,2]]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have the rep. to upvote you, but I follow you now.  I didn't know how ImageTrim worked!

Comment: @RVoight Please note that you still have to mask this! Otherwise you work on all the image values and not only on the ones from your component.

Comment: @halirutan: He doesn't if his components are all rectangular (because of `Method -> "BoundingBox"`). Otherwise, you're right of course. I just wanted to show how BoundingBox and ImageTrim can work together and didn't want to complicate things with masking.

Comment: @nikie Ahh, haven't notice this before.

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you use the `"Mask"` for a component to separate it in the original image?

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "JellyBeans"}];
m = MorphologicalComponents[
   Binarize@ColorNegate[ColorConvert[image, "Grayscale"]]];

mask = ComponentMeasurements[m, "Mask"];
ImageMultiply[image, Image[3 /. mask]]
```

In this way you can extract from the original image

[image: Mathematica graphics]

the 3rd component

[image: Mathematica graphics]

### Answer to your comment

`ImageTrim` as suggested by nikie is better than using `ImageTake` because you can give it the bounding box directly.

```
mask = ComponentMeasurements[m, {"Mask", "BoundingBox"}];
ImageTrim[ImageMultiply[image, Image[First[# /. mask]]], 
   Last[# /. mask]] & /@ Range[Length[mask]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's great to know we can do this, but how do I then crop to a bounding box around that component (my components are already rectangular)?

Comment: @RVoight You just use `"BoundingBox"` as additional measure and provide this to `ImageTake`. Be careful, because the ordering of the min/max box values is different and you have to incorporate the image dimensions in y direction.