# Can I split an image into subparts automatically?

Tags: image-processing

I want to extract subimages from an image like below.
There are 6 components in the image, I want to crop this image into 6 images in a way each individual image contain only 1 component. 
Can I automatically do it by *Mathematica*?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ImagePartition[  ]` or `MorphologicalComponents[ ]`?

Comment: Welcome! Can you please elaborate? At the moment it is not clear what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: Look up `ComponentMeasurements` and `ImageTrim` in the documentation.

Comment: @HayashiYoshiaki Look at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35249/how-can-i-properly-partition-intensitydata-output-from-componentmeasurements)

Comment: There are 6 components in the image, I want to crop this image into 6 images in a way each individual image contain only 1 component.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks martin !!

```
SplitImage[image_] := Module[
  {m, components},
  m = MorphologicalComponents[image];
  components = 
   ComponentMeasurements[{m, image}, {"Area", "BoundingBox"},#1>100&];
  ImageTrim[image, #] & /@ components[[All, 2, 2]]
]
```

[image]