# Split a (complex) image into sub parts

Tags: image-processing

I'm aware of the [solution to a similar problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109154/can-i-split-an-image-into-subparts-automatically/109157#109157) by Hayashi Yoshiaki. Is there a way of extending the solution to break out the chromosomes from this example I have a mass of data in this format that needs to be converted to a training set. Note the there are holes in the chromosome that the human ignores when segmenting. Doing this manually for hundreds of images is a challenge. Thanks in advance

[image: Example subset of images of chromosome]

Comment: Please give a link to Yoshiaki's solution.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109154/can-i-split-an-image-into-subparts-automatically/109157#109157

Comment: Are all your images aligned and roughly equally spaced like this one?

Comment: Yes, thats right.  They are autogenerated. some are long and bent but all are essentially equidistant.

Comment: This image looks pretty easy to divide, to the extent that a very straightforward algorithm can be written (basically - detecting columns that are almost totally white). It would be helpful if you could provide a few more samples so that we can check the robustness.

Comment: @Boris, you say that these images are autogenerated. If so then, could you have each chromosome take exactly the same horizontal space? Then you would just need `ImagePartitions[image, Scaled[{1/17,1}]`. At this time, that approach doesn't work because the widths are different for different chromosomes unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the very straightforward method I suggested in my comment:

```
tot = Total@ImageData[Binarize[im, 0.9]];
columnsSequence = Flatten@Position[tot, x_ /; x >= 103];
columns = Round@(Mean /@ Split[columnsSequence, #2 - #1 == 1 &]);
imd = ImageData[im];
imd[[All, columns, All]] = 0;
Image[imd]
```

This is just drawing the lines that separate the chromosomes. From here you can split the image or do any other further manipulation. For calculating the best separating "white column" I used [this trick](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23608/367).

[image]

Here's how to divide the image to subimages:

```
imd=ImageData[ims]
images = Table[
  imd[[All, columns[[i]] ;; columns[[i + 1]], All]], {i, 
   Length[columns] - 1}]
Image /@ images
```

[image]

Comment: OK, its a good start - how do I generate a list of images from this? I'll post a page of data from one example in the morning.

Comment: Hi yohbs, Ive tested your routine on other sets and find that I need to adjust the position parameter but thats OK I can automate  that. Im having trouble breaking out the individual components due to my limited familiarity with array handling. I shall persevere.

Comment: this seems to work- not elegant Im afraid:

Comment: pt1 = Drop[Partition[Riffle[columns, 0], 2], -1];
pt2 = Drop[Partition[Riffle[columns, 116], 2], 1];
components = 
 Partition[Partition[Flatten[Transpose[{pt1, pt2}]], 2], 2]; images = 
 ImageTrim[im, #] & /@ components

Comment: @Boris You can do it more cleanly. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @ yohbs  just seen your edit - worth the wait.