# Create the source image for this cool animated illusion

Tags: image-processing, image, visualization

Have a look at this very awesome video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvvcRdwNhGM

You have a vertically discretized image, which is composed of 5 or 6 images, which are shifted by an increment, as large as the line width of the comb. 
[image]

When you move the comb you display always one of those images, and hence create the illusion of movement:

[image]

I would like to create the background images to print out using Mathematica.

**Input:** Image or video sequence
+ Line width of grid (distance between two black lines)

**Output:** image to print out and use as background image behind the comb

*Steps for the *Mathematica* code:*

*n*: distance between each black line

*m*: number of input images

Let's try to animate a flying bird:

[image]

1. Cut out vertical slices from each image.
   The slice width should be equal to the distance between each black line *n* multiplied by the number of input pictures *m*.

[image]

2. Reassemble all the pictures, but each picture should be translated by *m*(i)*n*.

It would be awesome to see it work.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: What have you tried? Any work that you've done would be interesting, including if you have separated the bird image into one image per bird.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

## TUTORIAL

---

### Import Image

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzcUg.jpg"]
```

[image]

### Split into Components

Using [this approach](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35251/22013) (credit: nikie):

```
m = MorphologicalComponents[Binarize@ColorNegate[ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"]]];
Colorize[m]
```

[image]

```
components = ComponentMeasurements[{m, img}, {"Area", "BoundingBox"}, #1 > 100 &];

trim = ImageTrim[img, #] & /@ components[[All, 2, 2]]
```

[image]

There's a problem with `trim[[3]]` and `trim[[4]]`, so:

### Trim Component nr 3

```
trim[[3]] = RemoveBackground @ DeleteSmallComponents @ RemoveBackground @ trim[[3]]
```

[image]

### Trim Component nr 4

```
trim[[4]] = RemoveBackground @ DeleteSmallComponents @ RemoveBackground @ trim[[4]]
```

[image]

### Component Images

```
trim
```

[image]

```
dim = ImageDimensions /@ trim
```

> {{299, 272}, {301, 256}, {262, 231}, {262, 253}, {302, 255}, {281, 
>     269}, {261, 252}, {261, 231}}

```
ListAnimate @ trim

trim = ImageResize[#, {304, 270}] & /@ trim
```

I decided on the above `{304, 270}` so that `304` will be easily divisible by 8 later.

```
dim = ImageDimensions /@ trim

ListAnimate @ trim
```

[image]

### Image Cuts

This is the proper part; I made it very crude just to show the approach and how does it work. The details, like the number of slices, their widths and heights etc. should be thought through.

```
cuts = Plus[#, {1, 0}] & /@ Partition[FindDivisions[{1, 304, 38}, 8], 2, 1]
```

> {{1, 38}, {39, 76}, {77, 114}, {115, 152}, {153, 190}, {191, 
>     228}, {229, 266}, {267, 304}}

```
slices = Table[ImageTake[trim[[i]], {1, 270}, #] & /@ cuts, {i, 8}]
```

[image]

### Reassemble

```
reas = Flatten @ Table[Flatten[slices][[i ;; 64 ;; 8]], {i, 8}]
```

[image]

```
reas2 = ImageAssemble[ConformImages @ reas]
```

[image]

### Moving Window

```
ImageDimensions @ reas2
```

> {2432, 270}

```
window = ImageAssemble @
  Table[ImagePad[#, {{38, 0}, {0, 0}}, Directive@Transparent] & @
    ImageResize[Graphics[Rectangle[]], {304 - 38, 270}], 8]
```

[image]

```
Overlay[{reas2, window}]
```

[image]

### Slide

Make a set of windows:

```
windows = 
 Table[ImageAssemble @
   RotateRight[First @ ImagePartition[window, {38, 270}], i], {i, 0, 7}]
```

[image]

Make a set of `Overlay`s:

```
seq = Overlay[{reas2, #}] & /@ windows
```

[image]

Finally:

```
ListAnimate @ seq
```

[image]

---

---

[image]

The last gif doesn't really look like a flying bird due to the ratios etc. So now I'll repeat the steps from **Image Cuts** on with modifications to make it look nicer.

### Image Cuts

Let's stick to the width of each component equal to `304`;

```
Divisors @ 304
```

> {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 19, 38, 76, 152, 304}

Let's make `16` slices of each component, each slice be of width `19` pixels:

```
cuts = Plus[#, {1, 0}] & /@ Partition[FindDivisions[{1, 304, 19}, 16], 2, 1]
```

> {{1, 19}, {20, 38}, {39, 57}, {58, 76}, {77, 95}, {96, 114}, {115, 
>     133}, {134, 152}, {153, 171}, {172, 190}, {191, 209}, {210, 
>     228}, {229, 247}, {248, 266}, {267, 285}, {286, 304}}

```
slices = Table[ImageTake[trim[[i]], {1, 270}, #] & /@ cuts, {i, 8}]
```

[image]

### Reassemble

There are

```
Length @ Flatten @ slices
```

> 128

slices, so

```
reas = Flatten @ Table[Flatten[slices][[i ;; 128 ;; 16]], {i, 16}]
reas2 = ImageAssemble[ConformImages @ reas]
```

[image]

But here the image is stretched only horizontally, which makes it unproportional. Since

```
ImageDimensions @ reas2
```

> {2432, 270}

where $2432=304\times 8$, we need to `ImageResize` the image also vertically by a factor of `8`:

```
reas2 = ImageResize[reas2, {2432, 270*8}]
```

[image]

### Moving Window

Now the same trick with `window`:

```
window = ImageAssemble @
  Table[ImagePad[#, {{19, 0}, {0, 0}}, Directive@Transparent] & @
    ImageResize[Graphics[Rectangle[]], {304/2 - 19, 270 8}], 16]
```

[image]

Note that I'm quite insane, because

```
ImageDimensions @ window
```

> {2432, 2160}

(i.e., a resolution of a not bad TV ;)

The `Overlay` of two images looks nice:

```
Overlay[{reas2, window}]
```

[image]

### Slide

The same as before:

```
windows = 
 Table[ImageAssemble @
   RotateRight[First @ ImagePartition[window, {19, 270 8}], i], {i, 0, 7}]
```

[image]

```
seq = Overlay[{reas2, #}] & /@ windows
```

[image]

and finally

```
gif3 = ListAnimate@seq
```

Unfortunately, the gif is too big (2.3 MB) to upload it here, so you can see it on imgur: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bu2O.jpg

---

---

## Smaller-sized gif

The high-resolution (i.e., final `reas2` and `window`) should be perfect if one would really want to print it like on the [YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvvcRdwNhGM). To make a reasonable-size gif, let's resize `reas2` and `windows`:

```
reas3 = ImageResize[reas2, {304, 270}]

windows2 = ImageResize[#, {304, 270}] & /@ windows

seq2 = Overlay[{reas3, #}] & /@ windows2

ListAnimate @ seq2
```

and the gif is exported with

```
Export["gif4.gif", seq2, "DisplayDurations" -> 0.25]
```

[image]

---

There's also [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5oiM9CdlAA) showing how to draw a pacman by hand. That approach is equivalent to taking only four components, meaning that the black lines were 3x thicker than the transparent one (I refer to the `window` now), i.e. 75% of the window is black. In the above bird, $7/8=87.5\%$ is black, so there's not much space left to see the actual figure. So I'd say that the fewer the component images, the better. And also the animation rate is crucial.

(I now think that maybe `Gray` instead of `Black` would be better for the bird's `window`...)

---

Due to an invitation by Vitaliy Kaurov (thanks!), this answer has been also cross posted on http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/980590?p_p_auth=QTOfV64I and chosen to be among the Staff Picks.

Comment: Wow. Thanks a lot for your answer and your detailed explenation. This is great work! :) It would be anwesome, if someone also manages to animate the moving window.

Comment: @DoHe See the edited **Slide** part of my answer.

Comment: Perfect !! Thank you so much corey979 ! :)

Comment: For the `window = ImageAssemble@Table[..., 8]` part, you may want to replace `8` with `{8}` for compatibility with older Mathematica versions.

Comment: @corey970 Thank you so much for all your updates !! The results now already looks stunning on imgur !! Great work ! I am looking forward to your enhanced procedure !

Comment: @corey979 alright thans

Comment: The sequence of the images somehow got mixed when you trim the images in the beginning. The correct order is from left to right, top to bottom. But of course this does not change anything on the quality of your answer.

Comment: Congratulations on an elusive Guru badge!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you :) There are still many badges to get, though ;)

Comment: Always. ;^)  Only Leonid seems to find that Guru badge easy to grab.  This year I am finally getting them but they are on answers that have taken two to four years to accrue 40 votes.  Getting one in under a month is amazing.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That's probably because I have lots of colorful pictures in my answer, and people love lots of colorful pictures ;)

Answer (score 8):

I gave this a try too. Turns out this method works better for certain aspect ratios, and certain number of frames. My image isn't very suitable, but here we go. I got the image from [this](http://blaiprat.github.io/jquery.animateSprite/) website.

```
img = RemoveAlphaChannel@Import["http://blaiprat.github.io/jquery.animateSprite/img/scottpilgrim_multiple.png"];

{w, h} = {108, 140};
gap = 5;

{right, left} = ImagePartition[img, {w, h}];

right // GraphicsRow
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
background = ImageAssemble@Flatten@Transpose[
      First[ImagePartition[#, {gap, h}]] & /@ right
    ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The above is all you need for a printout. This for previewing the effect on the computer:

```
white = ConstantImage[White, {gap, h}];
black = ConstantImage[Black, {gap, h}];

frames = Table[
  mask = RotateRight[PadRight[{white}, Length[right], black], n];
  mask = ImageAssemble@PadRight[{}, Floor[w Length[mask]/gap], mask];
  ImageMultiply[background,mask], {n, 0, Length[right], 1}];
```

You can export the frames as a gif or look at them with `ListAnimate`.

```
Export["running.gif", frames]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe if you reduce the width of the black bars and increase the number, it will look much better. You could give it a try.

Comment: @DoHe The width of the black bars is the slice width times the number of frames. In order to decrease the width of the black bars you have to either remove frames (=> incomplete animation) or make the slice width smaller (=> more difficult for the brain to piece together the slices). At the beginning of my answer I gave two properties that I believe are important for this kind of animation to work well, if you have other ideas I'd be pleased if you showed some results but I'm not going to run your experiments for you.