# Image analysis: Gravel Sieve

Tags: image-processing

In this link:  http://broadwaysand.com/?page_id=165, you can find different gravel pictures.[image: pea gravel and sand]

A **quarter dollar** coin gives the scale, because its diameter is 0.955 inches (24.26 mm)

I want to get the Particle Size Distribution and plot the cummulative granulometry curve, this is the percentage of the material less than a given size.

I'm not very experienced on image analysis and I don't know where to start: How to calculate the picture size identifying the coin, and afterwards find the particle sizes.

[image]

Comment: I don't think this can be do accurately. you need to know that Sieve does not depend on the surface layer of the Gravel only. Sieve takes the whole mass of gravel. The picture shows only the first layer of the gravel.

Comment: You could start by taking a look at the following: [How to Count Cells](http://blog.wolfram.com/2012/01/04/how-to-count-cells-annihilate-sailboats-and-warp-the-mona-lisa/), [Optimal Binarize value for counting experiment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88067/27951), and [Count Elements in Image](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15921/27951).

Comment: Also, related Image Processing: Concrete test blocks http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27075/image-processing-concrete-test-blocks

Answer (score 12):

It will only be good for a rough estimate, but you can segment the image using `WatershedComponents` and then visualize the results

```
img = ColorConvert[Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3u7G.jpg"], "Grayscale"]; 
seg = WatershedComponents[img, Method -> {"MinimumSaliency", 0.5}];
seg // Colorize
```

[image]

Now you can use ComponentMeasurements to get the area of each colored region and then plot the results. Below I've plotted a histogram showing the number of detected particles (vertical axis) of each size (on the horizontal axis).

```
areaComp = ComponentMeasurements[seg, "Area"];
areas = areaComp[[All, 2]];
Histogram[areas]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[areas, "Log", "CDF"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks to @belisarius for the log histogram... that looks more like the plot the OP was expecting!

Comment: I thought exactly the same :)

Comment: `Area[D_] := (Pi/4)*D^2` so `Area[24.26 mm] = 462.244 mm^2`, as the coin looks larger than any other pebble the histogram should reach the 100% before 462 mm.

Comment: Nice  job bill s!

Comment: In fact, the largest segment is the coin, which has area 47949 pixels (it's the first element of `areas`).